# Last row of div grid is slightly out of alignment

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the last row of div squares is *slightly* out of alignment, and it's driving me crazy as to why it's happening.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ue936Lnn/

(HTML has been shortened to save pasting several hundred lines of the same thing.)

**HTML**

```
<body>        
    <div id="main_container">            
        <div id="content_container">
            <div id="square_container">
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <br>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                ...

                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <br>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
                <div class="tone_square"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #15181A;
}

#content_container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tone_square {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: white;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

#square_container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You realise you've got one line in your HTML that's missing the opening tag's `<` character? I'm assuming that's a typo *here*, rather than from your current code?

Comment: Please upload this to jsfiddle so that folks can tinker. Probably setting {font:0} in the right place may solve the issue, but I'd love to try it before writing it as the answer

Comment: @DavidThomas Woops! Typo here, yeah. Will fix. vivek, gotcha

Comment: @vivekmaharajh Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a forked version of you jsfiddle, with the problem solved:
https://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/caq07de2/

Whenever you use `inline` elements, you've got to watch out for hidden font-effects (since `inline` is text-based). You can solve this by either avoiding inline for non-text elements, or by setting `font-size:0` to eliminate font effects.

In your case, I set `font-size:0;` on `#square_container` and the issue went away.

(I also had to add `margin:2px;` to `.tone_square` to counter for the lost font-spacing).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I'll bear that in mind for the future.

Comment: It might be worth bringing the code into your answer (just in case JS Fiddle falls over), and creating a stack snippet ([edit], then use the button next to the image button in the editor to incorporate a live demo).

Comment: @DavidThomas This probably belongs on meta, but I think stackoverflow should either 1) update stack snippets to be as usable as jsfiddle, or 2) automatically ingest jsfiddle links.

Comment: Agreed, broadly; but it's still better to have the code in your answer (although it's not a major point, since you described where it goes), despite the lack of ease. Still: no down-votes or whatever, and it's entirely your call.